# Invoice each bundle product seperately

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, invoice, bundled-product

I would like to make a bundled product promotion in my shop. (1.7.0.2) To explain it as an example:

- Product A: 40$
- Product B: 25$
- Bundle (1x A + 2x B): Total Price is 70$ instead of 90$

I only want to give this offer with fixed quantities, so user shouldn't make any changes to item quantities. I've found the solution for this fixed quantity issue here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890908/grouped-product-with-fixed-sub-item-quantities

It lets me to use bundle product with no "user defined quantity" for each item.

I want to invoice each bundle item seperately. Like they are ordered seperately. When I create invoice as bundle product, it groups all sub products under main bundle product. Is this possible?